# how we can run hadoop program in eclipse in java

Tags: java, hadoop

i am working on hadoop but i am not able to understand how we can configure to eclipse and which software install to run hadoop program .in single machine in windows 7.
is there any plugin is available to run hadoop program . 
can you please suggest me any link detailed information how can i rum hadoop program.
i refer many sides but i am not getting exact information how can i run program .
is there any side getting all information about the hadoop.program running in eclipse 
and how can i map and reduce the program .

Comment: try this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/running-hadoop-mapreduce

Comment: they can not give detailed information or means step by step in windows operating system